# Lab constructing a rectangle in Java

Tags: java, methods, constructor, rectangles

I am new to programming and recently started on my computer science degree. Due to my son being sick I missed labs yesterday for CS-140/Java and am having a little trouble with my lab assignment from home.

1. I am told to Construct an empty Rectangle called box.
2. Figure out how to change the width of box to 50, its height to 60 and top-left corner to [100,50]. (You need to call appropriate methods on box to achieve this.)
3. Figure out how to compute the area of box. You have to get the height and width of box, by calling appropriate methods to compute the area.
4. Then print the value returned by calling a method on box and then we print a message that describes the value we expect to see.

I have searched through stack exchange and found some useful information but I still cannot figure out the bugs in the code and why it is not working. I am assuming the 63 errors are from something like a curly bracket in the beginning either missing or too many curly brackets.

I have 63 errors somehow the code I have entered so far is the following:

```
 import java.awt.Rectangle;
public class Rectangle {
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double width, height;

    public Rectangle(double x, double y, double w, double h) {{
           this.x = x;
           this.y = y;
           width = w;
           height = h;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Rectangle box = new Rectangle (100, 50, 50, 60);
       System.out.println(box);
    }
       System.out.println("Part 1:");
       System.out.println("-------");
       System.out.println("CREATING AN EMPTY Rectangle, SETTING ITS width TO 50, " +
                          "ITS height TO 60, AND ITS TOP LEFT CORNER TO (100, 50)");
       // Code for Part 1 goes here


        }

       System.out.println("Part 2:");
       System.out.println("-------");
       System.out.println("TESTING THE PERIMETER OF THE RECTANGLE "
                        + "CREATED IN PART 1 ABOVE");
       // Code for Part 2 goes here.  Use the same Rectangle
       // you used Part1

       // define a String reference called river and initialize it
       // to Mississippi.  Read the API to figure out which method 
       // to use to get the desired effect.
       System.out.println("Part 3:");
       System.out.println("-------");
       System.out.println("INITIALIZING river to Mississippi AND REPLACING "
                        + "EACH i to ! AND EACH s TO $");
       // code for Part 3 goes here


       System.out.println("Part 4:");
       System.out.println("-------");
       System.out.println("CONSTRUCTING A StringBuilder OBJECT INITIALIZED "
                        + "TO desserts AND REVERSING IT");
       // code for Part 4 goes here


       System.out.println("Part 5:");
       System.out.println("-------");
       System.out.println("CONSTRUCTING A Random OBJECT TO PLAY LOTTERY BY GENERATING ");
       System.out.println("6 RANDOM INTEGERS BETWEEN 1 and 49 (BOTH INCLUSIVE)");
       //code for Part 5 goes here

       System.out.println("Part 6:");
       System.out.println("-------");
       System.out.println("ADDING ONE DAY TO 2/28/2019, 2/28/2020, 2/28/2021 " +
                          "AND 2/28/2022 AND PRINTING THEM");
       // code for Part 6 goes here
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I am excited to join the community of StackOverflow and hopefully be able to contribute someday.

Comment: First remove those unwanted brackets to compile your code.

Comment: @secko Thank you for your assistance. I removed the incidental double brackets after public rectangle in the beginning, where are the other unnecessary brackets you see?

Comment: Please define "empty" Rectangle.

Comment: @Andreas I am assuming that means literally empty, nothing inside the box. I am fairly new to all this

Comment: Are you supposed to define your own Rectangle class, or are you supposed to use `java.awt.Rectangle`?

Comment: @AspiringProgrammer19 I updated my answer.

Comment: @StephenP It was not specified in the assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the cleanup of your code:

```
//import java.awt.Rectangle; // you probably autocompleted this line, since you created your own Rectangle class for console outputs
public class Rectangle {
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double width, height;

    public Rectangle(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
           this.x = x;
           this.y = y;
           width = w;
           height = h;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Rectangle box = new Rectangle (100, 50, 50, 60);
       System.out.println(box);

       System.out.println("Part 1:");
       System.out.println("-------");
       System.out.println("CREATING AN EMPTY Rectangle, SETTING ITS width TO 50, " +
                          "ITS height TO 60, AND ITS TOP LEFT CORNER TO (100, 50)");
       // Code for Part 1 goes here




       System.out.println("Part 2:");
       System.out.println("-------");
       System.out.println("TESTING THE PERIMETER OF THE RECTANGLE "
                        + "CREATED IN PART 1 ABOVE");
       // Code for Part 2 goes here.  Use the same Rectangle
       // you used Part1

       // define a String reference called river and initialize it
       // to Mississippi.  Read the API to figure out which method 
       // to use to get the desired effect.
       System.out.println("Part 3:");
       System.out.println("-------");
       System.out.println("INITIALIZING river to Mississippi AND REPLACING "
                        + "EACH i to ! AND EACH s TO $");
       // code for Part 3 goes here


       System.out.println("Part 4:");
       System.out.println("-------");
       System.out.println("CONSTRUCTING A StringBuilder OBJECT INITIALIZED "
                        + "TO desserts AND REVERSING IT");
       // code for Part 4 goes here


       System.out.println("Part 5:");
       System.out.println("-------");
       System.out.println("CONSTRUCTING A Random OBJECT TO PLAY LOTTERY BY GENERATING ");
       System.out.println("6 RANDOM INTEGERS BETWEEN 1 and 49 (BOTH INCLUSIVE)");
       //code for Part 5 goes here

       System.out.println("Part 6:");
       System.out.println("-------");
       System.out.println("ADDING ONE DAY TO 2/28/2019, 2/28/2020, 2/28/2021 " +
                          "AND 2/28/2022 AND PRINTING THEM");
       // code for Part 6 goes here
   }
}
```

The assignments are as follows:

```
      //assignment 1
      Rectangle box = new Rectangle(0,0,0,0);
      //assignment 2
      box.width = 50;
      box.height = 60;
      box.x = 100;
      box.y = 150;
      //assignment 3
      int area = box.height*box.width;
      //assignment 4
      System.out.println("Area: "+area);
```

I'm sure you can integrate this into your own code and make the appropriate methods as well as getters and setter if needed.

Comment: Thank you.This is helping quite a bit.

Comment: When I paste your code and then `javac Rectangle.java` it fails, and I get `Rectangle.java:68: error: Rectangle is already defined in this compilation unit` -- this is why I asked @AspiringProgrammer19 if s/he should be using `java.awt.Rectangle` or defining his/her own... you can't have them both (with Java8)

Comment: @StephenP Yeah, I agree with that, but since he included it and wrote a whole class named Rectangle it overwrites the awt.Rectangle. I assume they didn't cover Frame or JFrame yet, so no 2D graphics are needed. Remove awt.Rectangle and it should compile fine.

Comment: @stephenp I got the same error message and changed the title of the public class to Rectangle1 and this resolved that issue

Comment: @AspiringProgrammer19 yeah because you confused Rectangle (your class) and awt.Rectangle, which you probably autocompleted with some IDE.

Comment: @AspiringProgrammer19 rather than rename the class I just deleted the `import java.awt.Rectangle;` line, like Secko has (now) commented it out in his answer. Leaving in the import is still confusing, because you aren't actually using the AWT Rectangle class.

Comment: @Secko Thank you for the help, I have gotten 90% of the assignment completed!

Comment: Hi @Secko — if you'd add some explanation in your answer about what you changed and why I'd be happy to upvote.

Comment: @StephenP I didn't change anything, I just added the assignments as a solution to the answer. On the upper code I only commented out the aws.Rectangle inclusion line not to confuse anyone. So, that new code, is the answer to his assignments in his question.

Comment: Oh sorry @Secko -- I meant what you've changed from the OP's code in the question, not what you've changed in edits to your answer. IMHO posting code without saying what you've changed from the OP and why it makes a difference is not very useful to future readers; it is probably very helpful to the OP, but it should be helpful to future readers that find your answer via google search too.  Among other things, you've removed extraneous `{` and `}` and could explain those.

Answer (score 0):

The answers to all of these questions can be found on the Java documentation for [Rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html). I don't want to spoonfeed, so here's some of my observations.

- Use one of the constructors to set dimensions.
- Use some of the methods to read each dimension (height, width, etc)
- Calculate using formula for area.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance Hazim, I don't want to be spoonfed the answers either. I am just trying to figure out why there are so many compiler errors. Have i constructed the rectangle correctly? Thankfully all my errors occur after my code that was written and added to the original template.